# Keil uvision 5 unable to download flash

Tags: stm32, keil

Trying to write flash on stm32F100rbt6b discovery board but in console get only

Command not supported
Error: Flash Download failed  -  Target DLL has been cancelled
Flash Load finished at 12:11:48

Without any error code or something specific. Is it possible somehow to enable error log during flash loading?

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Can you add your MDK version?

Comment: You could try the [`STM32_Programmer_CLI`](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) to get more information as it has more options and prints everything out in text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the SWD connection has been corrupted, or the AHB has hung internally somehow.

You can log accesses if it is supported by the probe which you use (CMSIS-DAP, or ULINK). Under 'debug options', you can enable logging of all of the accesses (which is pretty verbose). It is greyed out here (since my session is active):

[image: Keil debug options]

Logs go into the current project area, and include DP/AP accesses as well as memory transfers.

Comment: it seems that i do not have such option.

Comment: It looks like STLINK doesn't support logging, at least not when used like this within Keil.